# Array to string conversion error in Radio

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, radio-button

```
$data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' ");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{ 
 $db_id = $rows['id'];
 $array[] = array($db_id);
}

 foreach($array as $value)
 {
echo '<input type="radio" name="change" value="'.$value.'"><br>';
}
```

I am getting an error on the **Radio line**.

```
Array to string conversion
```

But when I print_r the array, the values are perfectly fetched and assigned in the array.
What is the problem?

Comment: replace `$array[] = array($db_id);` with `$array[] = $db_id;`

Comment: thnks!! post it as answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lashane mentioned to assign, a value on the array you  need to use this syntax:

```
$array[] = $db_id;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are casting the id `$row['id']` to an array before assigning it to the `$array` variable replace

```
$db_id = $rows['id'];
$array[] = array($db_id); //casting the value to an array here
```

with

```
$array[] = $rows['id'];
```

Should alleviate the issue. I guess to be more clear, you're not really casting, rather assigning a new array with the value of `$row['id']` as its only value, none the less that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste following code :

```
 $data = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id='$id'");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
    { 
     $array[] = $rows['id'];
    }

     foreach($array as $value)
     {
      echo '<input type="radio" name="change" value="'.$value.'"><br>';
    }
```